# How to resolve FLS Create and FLS Update issue as per security scanner

Tags: apex, security-review, fls

Running the Security Scanner showed the Following Issues[image]

In order to avoid it I tried adding the following line

> ```
> if(Schema.sObjectType.SAP_Change_Event_Config__c.isCreateable())-
> ```
>
> For object and not for each field

But still the issue persist

```
if(Schema.sObjectType.SAP_Change_Event_Config__c.isCreateable()){
    List<SAP_Change_Event_Config__c> lstscec = new List<SAP_Change_Event_Config__c> ();
    SAP_Change_Event_Config__c scecObj = new SAP_Change_Event_Config__c();
    scecObj.Name = 'EKPO-EREKZ' ; 
    scecObj.CDOBJCL__c = 'EINKBELEG' ; 
    scecObj.DDTEXT__c = 'Purchasing Document Item';
    scecObj.Field__c = 'EREKZ' ;
    scecObj.Field_Description__c = 'Purchasing Document';
    scecObj.Field_Screen_Label__c = 'Final Invoice';
    scecObj.IsActive__c = true ;
    scecObj.OBTEXT__c = 'Purchasing Document' ;
    scecObj.Table__c = 'EKPO';
    
    lstscec.add(scecObj);
    
    scecObj = new SAP_Change_Event_Config__c();
    scecObj.Name = 'EKPO-WEBRE'; 
    scecObj.CDOBJCL__c = 'EINKBELEG'; 
    scecObj.DDTEXT__c = 'Purchasing Document Item' ;
    scecObj.Field__c = 'WEBRE';
    scecObj.Field_Description__c = 'Purchasing Document';
    scecObj.Field_Screen_Label__c = 'GR-Based IV';
    scecObj.IsActive__c = true;
    scecObj.OBTEXT__c = 'Purchasing Document';
    scecObj.Table__c = 'EKPO';
    
    lstscec.add(scecObj);
    
    scecObj = new SAP_Change_Event_Config__c();
    scecObj.Name = 'JEST-STAT'; 
    scecObj.CDOBJCL__c = 'ORH'; 
    scecObj.DDTEXT__c = '';
    scecObj.Field__c = 'STAT' ;
    scecObj.Field_Description__c = 'Production Order Status';
    scecObj.Field_Screen_Label__c = 'PO Status';
    scecObj.IsActive__c = true;
    scecObj.OBTEXT__c = '';
    scecObj.Table__c = 'JEST';
    
    lstscec.add(scecObj);
```

How can it be avoided??Any Suggestions?Should we keep checking this for each field??Or is there any simple way?

Comment: Can you check this also `Schema.sObjectType.SAP_Change_Event_Config__c.fields.Name.isCreateable()`

Comment: Yeah that is fine,But I don't want to keep repeating the same for each field.Is there any simple way to avoid adding it for each field?

Comment: Do you have any idea on why it is showing 'lstsec' and 'add' as an error?If we rectify the fields, will that too get resolved??

Comment: That's how scanner highlight the affected lines. After enforcing fls and crud check it will be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Just checking for object permission is not enough. You need to explicitly check it for every field being changed/set in your code. Because fields have their own accessibility settings called FLS.

If you add the below check

```
Schema.sObjectType.SAP_Change_Event_Config__c.fields.Name.isCreateable() &&
Schema.sObjectType.SAP_Change_Event_Config__c.fields.CDOBJCL__c.isCreateable() &&
Schema.sObjectType.SAP_Change_Event_Config__c.fields.DDTEXT__c.isCreateable() &&
// and so on..
```

*Use `isUpdateable` in case you are updating the existing record.

**Util Method**

If you want you can use a utility method as well as below:

```
public static Boolean isCreateable(Schema.SObjectType objectType, List<String> fields){
    Boolean retVal = false;
    Map<String, SObjectField > fieldsMap = objectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for(String fname: fields){
        // If the fields do not exists then we can skip and there will be no change in the DB
        if(!fieldsMap.containsKey(fname) || fieldsMap.get(fname).getDescribe().isCreateable()){
            retVal = true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

> Note this method should be written in the same class where you want to
>   check the accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a utility class/method and pass object name and corresponding fields as list to be check while each dml.
Refer this link for sample code.
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS